# Running .JAR file from java code (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, processbuilder

Im trying to run a jar file from java code, But unfortunately does not success.
A few details about the jar file:

1. The jar file located in a different folder (For example - "Folder").
2. The jar file using a files and folders are in the root folder (the same "Folder" i mentioned above).

What im trying to do so far:

**JAR file project.**

1. In netbeans i checked that the main class are defiend (Project properties -> Run -> Main Class).

**Other JAVA program**

1. Trying to run with the command:

   ```
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -jar "C:\\Software\\program.jar");
   ```

   **&&**

   ```
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -jar "C:\\Software\\program.jar" "C:\\Software");
   ```

   The jar file opened well, But he doesnt know and recognize his inner folders and files (the same "Folder" i mention above).
   In short, it does not recognize its root folder.
2. Trying to run with ProcessBuilder

   ```
          ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "javaw", "-jar", "C:\\Software\\program.jar");
       pb.directory(new File("C:\\Software"));
       try {
           pb.start();
       } catch (IOException ex) {

       }
   ```

In Some PC's **its works fine**, But in other pc's its not work and i got an error message: "Could not find the main class" 
** Offcourse if i run the jar with double click its works.

**So how can i run a jar file from other java program ?**

Comment: Does your commands work from command line? (I suspect that .exec might not be the problem)

Comment: @Stefan - Hi, my commands work fine from command line (But still the same problem with the root folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) variant of .exec where you specify working folder as the third argument. (In your examples, you always only use one argument.)

```
exec("javaw -jar "C:\\Software\\program.jar", null, "C:\\Software");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call it something like below. There are 2 types of calling it.

```
public class JarExecutor {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

//This is first way of calling.

```
Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar" ,"C:\\Users\\Leno\\Desktop\\JarsPractise\\JarsPrac.jar"});
```

//This is second way of calling.

```
    Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-cp","C:\\Users\\Leno\\Desktop\\JarsPractise\\JarsPrac.jar","com.shiva.practise.FloydTriangle"});
    proc.waitFor();
    BufferedInputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
    byte[] byt=new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(byt,0,byt.length);
    System.out.println(new String(byt));

}
```

}